# Listen to message from an IP from another machine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, udp

I am trying to send a message to Unity through UDP. The machine that sends the message has IP as `192.16.14.1` and port as `3034`. How do I enter these two inside of Unity application? I have found a code to listen for UDP messages but I cannot set the IP address here. Also the Unity application should be running at all times even if the message from another machine is sent or not.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using UnityEngine;

public class UDP_Listen : MonoBehaviour
{
    UdpClient clientData;
    int portData = 3034;
    public int receiveBufferSize = 120000;

    public bool showDebug = false;
    IPEndPoint ipEndPointData;
    private object obj = null;
    private System.AsyncCallback AC;
    byte[] receivedBytes;

    void Start()
    {
        InitializeUDPListener();
    }
    public void InitializeUDPListener()
    {
        ipEndPointData = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, portData);
        clientData = new UdpClient();
        clientData.Client.ReceiveBufferSize = receiveBufferSize;
        clientData.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, optionValue: true);
        clientData.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
        clientData.EnableBroadcast = true;
        clientData.Client.Bind(ipEndPointData);
        clientData.DontFragment = true;
        if (showDebug) Debug.Log("BufSize: " + clientData.Client.ReceiveBufferSize);
        AC = new System.AsyncCallback(ReceivedUDPPacket);
        clientData.BeginReceive(AC, obj);
        Debug.Log("UDP - Start Receiving..");
    }

    void ReceivedUDPPacket(System.IAsyncResult result)
    {
        //stopwatch.Start();
        receivedBytes = clientData.EndReceive(result, ref ipEndPointData);

        ParsePacket();

        clientData.BeginReceive(AC, obj);

        //stopwatch.Stop();
        //Debug.Log(stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);
        //stopwatch.Reset();
    } // ReceiveCallBack

    void ParsePacket()
    {
        // work with receivedBytes
        Debug.Log("receivedBytes len = " + receivedBytes.Length);
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (clientData != null)
        {
            clientData.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are two different things:

- You want to define the **receiving local** port you [`Bind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.bind)  your socket to
- You want to define the expected **sending remote** ip + port you want to [`Receive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receive) from

Currently you are using the very same one

```
ipEndPointData = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, portData);
```

for both! *(Fun fact: As a side effect by using always the same field you basically allow **any** sender but are then bond to that specific sender from this moment on)*

Actually a lot of things you configure there are the default values anyway so here is more or less what I would do

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;

public class UDP_Listen : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ushort localReceiverPort = 3034;
    
    public string senderIP = "192.168.111.1";
    public ushort remoteSenderPort = 3034;

    public bool showDebug = false;

    // Thread-safe Queue to handle enqueued actions in the Unity main thread
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Action> mainThreadActions = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();

    private Thread udpListenerThread;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        // do your things completely asynchronous in a background thread
        udpListenerThread = new Thread(UDPListenerThread);
        udpListenerThread.Start();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // in the Unity main thread work off the actions
        while (mainThreadActions.TryDequeue(out var action))
        {
            action?.Invoke();
        }
    }

    private void UDPListenerThread()
    {
        UdpClient udpClient = null;

        try
        { 
            // local end point listens on any local IP
            var localEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, localReceiverPort);
            udpClient = new UdpClient(localEndpoint);
            
            if (showDebug)
            {
                Debug.Log("BufSize: " + clientData.Client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            }

            Debug.Log("UDP - Start Receiving..");

            // endless loop -> ok since in a thread and containing blocking call(s)
            while (true)
            {
                // remote sender endpoint -> listens only to specific IP
                var expectedSenderEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(senderIP), remoteSenderPort);
                
                // blocking call - but doesn't matter since this is a thread
                var receivedBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref expectedSenderEndpoint);

                // parse the bytes here
                // do any expensive work while still on a background thread
                
                mainThreadActions.Enqueue(() =>
                {
                    // Put anything in here that is required to happen in the Unity main thread
                    // so basically anything using GameObject, Transform, etc 
                });
            }
        }
        // thrown for "Abort"
        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        {
            Debug.Log("UDP Listener terminated");
        }
        // Catch but Log any other exception
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogException(e);
        }
        // This is run even if an exception happend
        finally
        {
            // either way dispose the UDP client
            udpClient?.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        udpListenerThread?.Abort();
    }
}
```

I'm sure the same can be done also using the `BeginReceive`/`EndReceive` or task based alternatives but since it is going to run endless anyway I personally find a thread often easier to read and maintain.

Comment: I thought the port for sending and receiving should be the same

Answer (score 1):

If the Unity application is to be receiving the messages constantly, it needs to be something like:

```
UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(11000);
IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.16.14.1"), 3034);

while (true)
{
    byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
}
```

This should read only calls from the specific IP, not sure which port you want the UDPClient to read out from (specified in the UDPClient constructor) but you can set this to whatever you need it to be.

Answer (score -1):

I think you got it backwards. This code you shared is for, like you said, listen UDP protocol on desired port. This piece of code needs to be inside your "server". By server try to understand that as the receiving side.

on your shared method InitializeUDPListener(); we have this piece:

```
ipEndPointData = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, portData);
```

this means you are initializing your udp socket to listen for ANY ip adresses at the given port. That said, you have your server ready to go,  what you need to do is setup the client side, the one who sends the message.

here some example:

```
    public string serverIp = "127.0.0.1"; // your server ip, this one is sending to local host 
public int serverPort = 28500; // your server port



public void ClientSendMessage()
{
    Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

    IPAddress broadcast = IPAddress.Parse(serverIp);

    byte[] sendbuf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("THIS IS A MESSAGE FROM CLIENT!");

    IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(broadcast, serverPort);

    s.SendTo(sendbuf, ep);


}
```

I encourage you to read about UDP/TCP protocols before using them. MS has documentation with details.

here some links:

[TCP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/using-tcp-services)

[UDP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/using-udp-services)

[Sockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/sockets)

Comment: OP states: `I am trying to send a message to Unity through UDP` .. the code that OP shows and what OP's question is about is the receiving **receiving** part on the Unity side ;)

Comment: @derHugo "I have found a code to listen for UDP messages but I cannot set the IP address here"; Op clearly doesnt know how UDP sockets works. You're assuming what op wants, I dont see how this could be downvoted.

Comment: OP states `The [remote/server] machine that sends the message has IP as 192.16.14.1 and port as 3034` -> `How do I enter these two [for receiving] inside of Unity application` .. again: OP wants o receive using the code that is shown and its almost correct except for passing in the wrong remote endpoint. OP is not asking for how to send something via UDP but for how to receive .. therefore this answer isn't on point ;)